# Codeigniter - Using RESTful web services in the MVC framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I am fairly new to programming in php and learning as I go. I recently started using an MVC framework (codeigniter) and I am now trying to learn the use of RESTful web services.

What I have trouble understanding is how the REST services fit into the MVC framework.

I have a basic proposal building system where the user walks through several forms and at the end I gather that information and create a formatted pdf for them.

I am using the https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver REST library and what I have done so far is wherever the information needs to be saved, updated or deleted in the program I have written the endpoint for the api to do that here is an example:

```
class Proposal extends REST_Controller 
{

   function __construct()
   {
    // Construct the parent class
    parent::__construct();
    //load model
    $this->load->model('proposal_model'); 

   }

   public function list_get()
   {
    // Users from a data store e.g. database
    $system = $this->proposal_model->get_proposals(); 
    json_encode($system); 
    $this->response($system, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);   
   }
}
```

Here is the Model I am calling the data from:

```
Class proposal_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function get_proposals() {

    //get proposal fields for realted table
    $sql = 'SELECT  proposal_name, 
                    customer_name, 
                    date_purchased, 
                    product_purchased
            FROM proposals 
            WHERE 1'; 

    $queryProposals = $this->db->query($sql);


    return $queryProposals->result();
  }
```

My main question is that it seems like the api endpoint replaces the controller, is this how it works? I am struggling a little bit to understand the flow of the architecture with RESTful services.

P.S I know the program I mentioned seems like it probably doesn't need the complication of REST but this is the first step in several programs which will all be using the same data source.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with `the api endpoint replaces the controller` but a RESTful API should be able to return data in JSON, XML or any other format depending on how you have setup them and what you allow. If you call a URL and that is an endpoint then yes, the response should be a RESTful response and not a controller response. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Comment: @ReynierPM what I meant was that it seems the api is replacing the controller to some extent. My controller was pointing to the model formatting it and returning it to the view. This seems to be taken care of the api call. The controller seems redundant.

Comment: Then what about if you try to remove the controller and call the same action and see what happens? That will give you the answer you're looking for :)

Comment: I kind of see your point. So does the controller make the call to the api -> which grabs data from the model ->  returns it to the controller -> spits out to the view?

Comment: I don't know how this work on CI and the plugin|module you're using but I have used a RESTful bundle before on Symfony2 and how it works is that in your controller your define some annotations to make the method be part of the API response so you'll be able to return data in JSON, XML or any other type depends on the configuration you've made. You can take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html) and grab the theory and should be the same as for CI + your module